# Text on both sides of some other text

Tags: html, css, layout, window, word-wrap

I'm working on a webpage with a certain design: I would like to get text to be on both sides of some other text, and when the browser window is narrowed, I would like for all the text to be below the original text. The situation is as in the picture below, with a wide browser window on the left and a narrow one on the right.

[image]

It would be great if the text would continue from the left side to the right side. If that's not possible, then I wouldn't mind the text on the top right starting where the text on the middle left ended. Honestly, the "Text 2" part is just a bunch of small pictures (all of which I want to appear somewhere on the page), so the order in which they appear does not matter.

What matters is that when the browser window is wide, the space near the top of the page gets filled first, and then moving down to the bottom. And when the page is narrowed, more space down below gets filled, until no more space is left on the sides, so everything is in the bottom (when the window is narrowest).

So far I have tried looking at floating a `div` in the center of the page, but that doesn't allow me to have text on both sides. Also if I have 3 columns, then I may lose some of the "Text 2" when the browser window is narrowed. "Text 1" has fixed width and height, and "Text 2" has variable width and height. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Not possible with CSS just yet...although CSS regions with text-flow is coming. Even then though all HTML elements are rectangles so you can't really have cutouts like that.